# Реализация Push Notifications в приложении

Tags: java, android, уведомления, pushup

Добрый день. Хотел услышать совет по одному вопросу затронувшему меня. 
Есть сайт управляемый CMS Wordpress, регистрация на нем отсутствует, но частенько выходят "акции" осуществляющиеся через функцию "записи". Также у меня написано apk с определенным функционалом, одним из которых является парсинг этих "акций" при помощи REST API. Все идеально работает. Теперь собственно вопрос. Возможно ли, и какие варианты имеются для реализации Push up уведомления при добавлении новой записи на сайте, не имея при этом зарегистрированных пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что вам могут подойти [топики](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).

Топик - что-то типо канала на который можно подписать/отписаться со стороны клиентов и отправлять пуш уведомления со стороны сервера.

Чтобы отправить в топик сообщение, Вам не нужно знать конкретные токены пользователей. Достаточно знать название канала и API KEY

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Т.е. пользователей можно без их ведома подписать и слать уведомления?

Comment: Да, в интерфейсе это отображать не обязательно. Имеено это вы имеете ввиду говоря "без их ведома" ?

Comment: Да, мне необходимо, чтобы каждое приложение могло получать уведомлении как только происходит публикация новой записи на сайте.